# axios data is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to perform an axios get request.

```
  axios
  .get("http://10.10.0.145/api/session", {
      headers: {
          'Cookie' : user_cookie
      }
  },         
  )
  .then(res => {
  
      result = res.data;
      id_user_intervention = res.data.id;
      console.log(id_user_intervention); //IS NOT UNDEFINED

      
    })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
  console.log(id_user_intervention); //IS UNDEFINED
```

I need to use id_user_intervention outside the axios request. I assign res.data.id to id_user_intervention, but this variable is undefined outside the axios request...how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Log `res` to find out what keys you need. Right now, it says, effectively `res.data.data.id`

Comment: this explains how to handle axios with async/await https://stackabuse.com/making-asynchronous-http-requests-in-javascript-with-axios/

Comment: Would you be able to log out `res` and show the results here? You might not be accessing the `id` correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's better you learn [`async/await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) on `javascript`. Then, try the following solution:-

```
const testFunction = async () => {
  let id_user_intervention = null;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("http://10.10.0.145/api/session", {
      headers: {
        'Cookie': user_cookie
      }
    })
    id_user_intervention = response.data.id;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  return id_user_intervention;
}

const anotherFunction = async () => {
  const data = await testFunction();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Hope it will work properly.

Comment: the problem is that i must access id_user_intervention outside... if i call testFunction() and then I print id_user_interventions.. it is undefined again

Comment: Got it. Check my answer now.